# Using a class within a class

Tags: c++

I have a very specific question on a program I am writing which makes a battleship game.  I have the header file provided to me and I must implement the function definitions within the defined header file.  I will post my entire code, however, I am only having trouble implementing the function `void ship::printShip() const`. I need it to access information for a class within a class and I have a function provided that I am using under location `void print() const`, however, it wants me to create a pointer in order to access the information under print. I will post the function definitions and the header file along with the error message.

**Header file:**

```
#ifndef BATTLESHIP_H_
#define BATTLESHIP_H_

// coordinates (location) of the ship and shots
class location{
public:
    location(); // void constructor, assigns -1 to X 
    void pick(); // picks a random location
    void fire(); // asks the user to input coordinates of the next shot
    void print() const; // prints location in format "a1"

    // returns true if the two locations match
    friend bool compare(location, location);

private:
    static const int fieldSize = 5; // the field (ocean) is fieldSize X fieldSize
    int x;  // 1 through fieldSize
    char y; // 'a' through fieldSize
};

// contains ship's coordinates (location) and whether is was sunk
class ship{
public:
    ship(); // void constructor, sets sunk=false
    bool match(location&) const; // returns true if this location matches
    // the ship's location
    bool isSunk() const { return sunk; } // checks to see if the ship is sunk
    void sink();       // sets "sunk" member variable of the ship to true
    void setLocation(const location&); // deploys the ship at the specified location
    void printShip() const; // prints location and status of the ship

private:
    location loc;
    bool sunk;
};

// contains the fleet of the deployed ships
class fleet{
public:
    void deployFleet(); // deploys the ships in random locations
    // of the ocean
    bool operational() const; // returns true if at least
    // one ship in the fleet is not sunk
    bool isHitNSink(const location &); // returns true if there was a deployed
    // ship at this location (hit) and sinks it
    // otherwise returns false (miss)
    void printFleet() const; // prints out locations of ships in fleet

private:
    static const int fleetSize = 5; // number of battleships
    int check(const location &);          // returns index of the ship 
    // that matches location
    // -1 if none match
    ship ships[fleetSize];        // battleships of the fleet
};

#endif /* BATTLESHIP_H_ */
```

**Here are my function definitions:**

```
#include "battleship.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
const int FLEET_SIZE = 5;
const int FIELD_SIZE = 5;


void location::pick(){



        x = rand() % FIELD_SIZE;
        if (x == 0){
            x = 1;
        }
        y = rand() % FIELD_SIZE;
        switch (y)
        {

        case 0:
            y = 'A';
            break;
        case 1:
            y = 'B';
            break;
        case 2:
            y = 'C';
            break;
        case 3:
            y = 'D';
            break;
        case 4:
            y = 'E';
            break;
        }



}

void location::fire(void){

    cout << "Enter the number of the grid to fire on ";
    cin >>y;
    cout << "Enter the letter of the grid to fire on ";
    cin >> x;
}

void location::print() const{
    cout << y << x;
}

bool compare(location one,location two){
    if ((one.x == two.x)&&(one.y==two.y)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

location::location(){
    x = -1;
}

void ship::setLocation(const location& location){
    loc= location;
}

bool ship::match(location& location)const{

    if (compare(loc, location)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void ship::printShip()const{
    cout << loc.print << endl;
    cout << sunk << endl;

}

void ship::sink(){
    sunk = true;
}
```

**Here is the .cpp**

```
#include "battleship.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;


/// this is main function

const int FLEET_SIZE = 5;
const int FIELD_SIZE = 5;
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    //
    // checking location object
    // 

    location mySpot, userShot;
    mySpot.pick(); // selecting a new random location

    cout << "Randomly selected location is: "; mySpot.print();

    cout << "Input location: ";
    userShot.fire(); // having user input a location

    if (compare(mySpot, userShot))
        cout << "Random location matches user input.\n";
    else
        cout << "Random location does not match user input.\n";



    //
    // checking ship object
    //



    ship myShip;

    myShip.setLocation(mySpot); // placing ship at mySpot location

    if(myShip.match(userShot))
    cout << "myShip\'s location matches user input.\n";
    else
    cout << "myShip's location does not match user input.\n";

    if(!myShip.isSunk()){
    cout << "myship is not sunk yet, sinking it.\n";
    myShip.sink();
    }

    cout << "myShip\'s status is: "; myShip.printShip();



    //
    // checking fleet object
    // 

    /* // uncomment this part once you are done debugging above code
    fleet myFleet;

    myFleet.deployFleet(); // fleet is deployed at random locations

    if(myFleet.operational())
    cout << "Some ships of myFleet are still up.\n";

    if(myFleet.isHitNSink(userShot))
    cout << "there was a ship at userShot location, no it is sunk.\n";
    else
    cout << "there was no ship at userShot location.\n";

    cout << "myFleet\'s status is: "; myFleet.printFleet();
    */
}
```

Here is the error for `printShip() const`

```
Error   1   error C3867: 'location::print': function call missing argument list; use '&location::print' to create a pointer to member
```

If someone could just explain what I need to edit in order to make  `printShip() const` print the location of the ship as intended that is all need.

Comment: Stream manipulators need to be called with the stream as their argument, else how would the poor function/functor know which stream to affect? TL;DR: you need your `location::print()` member function to take the stream as its one and only parameter (by reference). You will also need to return the stream in order to enable chaining.

Comment: Check your parentheses.

Comment: I appreciate the answer of changing location::print() to a function that takes the stream as its parameter and returns it, however, I am not supposed to edit the header file in this project. If you can think of any solutions in which I won't have to change the function prototypes that would be great.

Comment: Thats not your problem. You can write output methods with std::cout hardwired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply missing the parentheses in the call to `location::print`:

```
void ship::printShip() const {
    cout << loc.print() << endl;
    cout << sunk << endl;
}
```

It happens. But learn to recognize the message from your compiler: `function call missing argument list` actually means: "if you want to write a function call, add an argument list." And "use '&location::print' to create a pointer to member" tries to tell you the alternative, i.e., when you really want a pointer to the method, use `&location::print`.

**Later**
`location::print()` doesn't return anything, so you might want to change that. Or just use that call as it prints to `cout` right now.

```
void ship::printShip() const {
  loc.print();
  cout << endl;
  cout << sunk << endl;
}
```

Comment: I add parenthesis and I get a red squiggle under my << and the following error:  Error 1 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion) t

Comment: Make up your mind: should the method print, or return something that is fit to print.

Comment: I changed it to this: void ship::printShip()const{
 loc.print() << endl;
 cout << sunk << endl;     I supposed putting cout in there was an error since the function does that already, however, I cannot get this to compile either.  I cannot change the function header that file is provided and their both void functions so I must work within those constraints.

Comment: These are the errors:                Error 1 error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list and --------Error 2 error C2568: '<<' : unable to resolve function overload

Comment: `loc.print()` doesn't return anything! - see the extension to the answer.

Comment: Using cout in the function definition when I had my print function already do it was my problem.  Problem resolved thanks.